# How to remove "Certain" (not all) empty lines, or two consequent empty lines in notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++

I know that there is a way to remove empty lines in the Notepad++ through the "Edit > Line Operation"; however, it either removes ALL empty lines (in case where the empty line is not containing any characters), OR it removes only empty lines containing no characters including a space character.

My goal is to choose which "empty line"s to be deleted. (For example, to delete those double empty lines where two consequent lines are empty; not those single empty lines. I need keep those single empty lines)

Super ideal is to combine this operation after-which one more lines containing a specific "String" is deleted through the .*String.* Search in "Regexp" mode.

Example:

```
</section>
  <!--One line empty line -->
  <section id="phone-number">

    <parts level="1">
      <part choice="NPXMA" name="NPXMA" desc_en="Phone Number - COUNTRY" desc_fr="Numéro de Téléphone - COUNTRY" costRetail="X.XX" costWholesale="4.50" period="monthly" applyCommission="true" visibleAtSignup="true" visibleAtPlanChange="true" />

      <part choice="NSCA00" name="NPXMA" desc_en="Phone Number Setup Fee" desc_fr="frais d'activation de numéro" costRetail="X.XX" costWholesale="X.XX" period="once" applyCommission="false" visibleAtSignup="true" visibleAtPlanChange="true" />


      <part choice="NPXMA" name="NPXMA" desc_en="Phone Number - United States" desc_fr="Numéro de Téléphone - États-Unis" costRetail="X.XX" costWholesale="X.XX" period="monthly" applyCommission="true" visibleAtSignup="true" visibleAtPlanChange="true" />
```

Does anyone help? is there actually any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: You could write your own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use `\r\n` to get the required results. It will make sure that it only removes double empty lines (with single ones, I suppose).

The below animated gif explains it.

[image]

Comment: This is satisfies my need. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @SaffaSeraj can you please accept it as an answer. Glad to help.